# Prevent "Commands Out of Sync" error from MySQL stored procedure called via AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a MySQL stored procedure that updates data across a set of tables (basically for one record in the principal table and related records in a set of child tables). It's called via AJAX through a PHP function. (That is, the AJAX call is to a PHP page, which ultimately calls this SP.) It was working fine, but now I'm trying to make it do one more thing and running into the "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" error.

The change is to store one more item in the principal table, but to do so may require adding an item to a child table (called ActionTopic). The page lets the user either choose from a dropdown or type in a new value. I've added two parameters to the SP: one is the PK chosen in the dropdown, the other is the new value typed in. In the SP, I've added the code below. It checks whether there was a new value typed in. If so, it calls another SP that checks whether the value typed in is already in the table and, if not, adds it. (I've tried with the code to check and add the record inline rather than in a separate SP and I have the same problem.)

```
if cNewTopic <> '' then
    -- First, make sure the new topic isn't already there
    call aoctest.AddActionTopic(cNewTopic);
    -- SELECT @iTopicID := iID FROM ActionTopic WHERE UPPER(Description) = UPPER(cNewTopic);
    SET @iTopicID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
else
    SET @iTopicID = Topic;
end if;
```

The page works if the user makes a choice from the dropdown. The problem only occurs when the user types in a new value. Even when I get the error, everything else works as expected. The new value is added to the child table, and the parent table and other children are updated as expected.

Interestingly, if I call the SP in MySQL Workbench with the same parameters (after ensuring that the new value isn't in the new table), it runs without error. The only odd thing I've noticed is that I get two rows in the Output section of MySQL Workbench rather than one. Both show the call to the SP. The first shows "1 row(s) returned" and a period of time, while the second shows "0 row(s) returned" and "-/0.000 sec". A call to the SP in MySQL Workbench where the new value is already in the table also shows two rows in the Output section, but the second one shows "1 row(s) returned".

Not sure whether any of the other code is needed here. If you think I need to show more, please ask.

UPDATE: Based on the comment from Pete Dishman, I took a harder look at where the error is occurring. It's not the original SP call giving an error. It's the next call to MySQL, which is still inside the Ajax call.

The code processing the result already had this code:

```
//not sure why next line should be needed.
mysqli_next_result($conn);
```

I tried both simply doubling the call to mysqli_next_result (that is, two in a row) and putting it into a loop along the lines Pete suggested. With two calls, I still get the same error. With a loop, I wait 30 seconds and then get error 500: Internal server error.

UPDATE 2: I tried with a loop for mysqli_more_results() (similar to the one in Pete Dishman's reply) and echoing a counter inside the loop. The code brought my internet connection to a crawl and I finally had to break out of it, but there were dozens of iterations of the loop. Just tried the following:

```
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        $result = mysqli_store_result($conn);
        mysqli_free_result($result);

        if (mysqli_more_results($conn)) {
            $result = mysqli_store_result($conn);
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        $allresult = getsubmissions($conn);
```

Found a noticeable delay before it failed.

Even if you can't tell me what's wrong, I'd appreciate ideas for how to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own problem by reworking the code that processes the result as follows:

```
        if (mysqli_more_results($conn)) {
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            mysqli_next_result($conn);
            $result = mysqli_store_result($conn);
            mysqli_free_result($result);

            if (mysqli_more_results($conn)) {
                mysqli_next_result($conn);
                $result = mysqli_store_result($conn);
                if (!is_null($result) and gettype($result)!== 'boolean') {
                    mysqli_free_result($result);
                }
            }
        }
        $allresult = getsubmissions($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the stored procedure is returning multiple result sets (the two rows in workbench).
When querying from php you need to retrieve both result sets before you can send another query, otherwise you get the "commands out of sync" error.

The documentation seems to imply this is only the case when using `mysqli_multi_query` but we have it in our code when using `mysqli_real_query`.

Our query code is along the lines of:

```php
mysqli_real_query($conn, $sql);

$resultSet = mysqli_store_result($conn);

while (!is_null($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet, MYSQLI_BOTH)))
{
    $results[] = $row;
}

mysqli_free_result($resultSet);

// Check for any more results
while (mysqli_more_results($conn))
{
    if (mysqli_next_result($conn))
    {
        $result = mysqli_store_result($conn);
        if ($result !== FALSE)
        {
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    }
}

return $results;
```

The code would be different obviously if you're using PDO, but the same principle may apply (See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php)

Comment: Thanks. That led me to realize the error wasn't occurring where I thought it was. See my update to the original post.